# Is it possible to detect when a user hits "stop" on their browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I've written a custom upload file script that uses an animated gif while the data is being received. I'd like to stop the animation if a user hits the "stop" button during an upload though.

Is it possible to detect when a user hits "stop"?

Comment: You can determine this server-side.

Comment: What is this "stop" button? Is it part of your user interface, or are you talking about some native browser control?

Comment: @Pointy I'm talking about a native browser control. Like, when you type in a url address and hit enter to load it. You also have, "refresh" and "stop" as options.

I'm basically trying to determine when and if a user interrupts their file upload.

Comment: @Brad How would I determine this server-side?

Comment: @Kaylub OK well I'm pretty sure the answer is "no", but I don't claim that opinion to be authoritative. I just doubt that browser designers would bother to build an infrastructure for partially-loaded pages.

Comment: @Pointy Is there any other way of detecting when a user interrupts a file upload?

Comment: @Kaylub Depends on your server-side application... you didn't mention what you wrote it in or anything else.  Basically, just detect the TCP connection closing prematurely.

Comment: @Brad I'm using PHP and Javascript. Any way I can detect the TCP connection closing prematurely with either of them?

Comment: Just an idea, could you possibly addEventListener with `abort` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/abort) to the upload or to something happening together with the upload? Maybe an `interval` that you set, and when the upload is completed you can clearInterval

Comment: Another wild guess: maybe one can override the `window.stop` function and add a custom event to the function, to be fired when this function is called. Then you can addEventListener to this custom event and know when the browser stopped loading!

Comment: If you're uploading through AJAX, the browser won't have a "stop" control. "stop" and "refresh" are the same button, and it's only "stop" when the browser is loading the new page, which doesn't happen during an AJAX request. If you're not using AJAX, then... you can't really script anything during the page transition, no?